# Simple Heaviside fourier transformation I'm having trouble with

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Actually a lot of them, but I think that when I find out where I'm doing something wrong, the rest should be easier.

I have a function

$$f(t)=H(T)7e^{-2|t|}$$

and because H(T) = 1 when t>0, I get to

$$F(w)=\int_{0}^\infty f(t)e^{-jwt} = \int_{0}^\infty 7e^{-2t-iwt}=\frac{-7e^{-iwt-2t}}{iw+2}, t=inf$$
$$=\frac{7}{iw+2}$$

Now the answer here is not the same as I get from Wolfram Alpha, and I can't get right answer to other similar functions either like

$$f(t)=H(T)7e^{-6(t+1)}$$

Comment: Well for one, that negative sign shouldn't exist because you subtract the $t=0$ from the $t\to \infty$ term

Comment: Good point, will edit.

Comment: As for the difference, what did Wolfram alpha give you? Extra factors of $i$ and $\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: Yeah, i in the dividend and the square root in the dividor

Comment: The square root comes from how mathematica defines the fourier transform which is $$F(f(t))(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-2 \pi i \omega t} \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Oh yeah, I'd forgotten that there were a ton of definitions for FT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your definition of fourier transform
$$F(f(t))(\omega) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(t) e^{-j \omega t} \mathrm dt$$

We obtain the fourier transform for $H(t)7e^{-2|t|}$

\begin{eqnarray*} 
F(f(t))(\omega) &=& \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}H(t)7e^{2|t|-j \omega t}\mathrm dt  \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^0 H(t)e^{2t-j \omega t} \mathrm dt + \int_0^{\infty}H(t)7e^{-2t-j\omega t} \mathrm dt \\
&=& 0 + \lim_{a \to \infty}\int_0^a7e^{-(2+j \omega)t} \mathrm dt \\
&=& \lim_{a\to \infty}\left.\frac{-7}{2+j\omega}e^{-(2+j\omega)t}\right|^a_0 = 0 + \frac{7}{2+j\omega} = \frac{7}{j(\omega - 2j)} = \frac{-7j}{\omega - 2j}
\end{eqnarray*}